# NSIS VersionCompare function throwing an error

Tags: installation, nsis

When I run the following code, I get the error:
!insertmacro: VersionCompareCall
Usage: Pop $(user_var: output)
Which seems to indicate that there's a problem in the VersionCompare function.  I know this is likely not the case, so what else is wrong with my function?

```
  !include "LogicLib.nsh"
  !include "WordFunc.nsh"
;<snip>

function .onInit
    setShellVarContext all
    !insertmacro VerifyUserIsAdmin
    ClearErrors
    Var /GLOBAL INSTALL_NET_481

    StrCpy $INSTALL_NET_481 "False"

    ReadRegStr $0 HKLM  "${NET481REG}" "Version"
    
    IfErrors install 0 
    ${VersionCompare} $0 "4.8.09037" $var
    ${If} StrCmp $var "0"
        Goto skip
    ${EndIf}
    ${If} StrCmp $var "2"
        Goto skip
    ${EndIf}
install: 
    StrCpy $INSTALL_NET_481 "True"
skip:
    ClearErrors
functionEnd
```

Comment: are you using IntelliSense to write the script? If it is not offering you a $var then it is not declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `$var`?

You get this error when trying to write to something that is not a variable.

Comment: I got var from the example You're right- var needed to be declared.  I also renamed it in case it was reserved.  That probably wasn't required.